# What is the functional behavior of the function mysql_insert_id()?

Tags: php, mysql

Keeping the fact in mind that there are other related threads related to the above question, I want to ask here my specific query. I am building an online application system which requires unique form number to be assigned for successful submitters. I know the documentation for the function mysql_insert_id(). But I want to clear the following typical situation : 
Say I am using the last inserted ID (Off course AUTO_INCREMENTED) to manufacturing the form number. Now say there are two concurrent users sitting at two different terminals trying to register into the system. If during migration from say registration.php page to registration_success.php page, the ID pertains to user1 and user2 are 20 and 21 respectively. What will be the ID carried for

Comment: As each user has a separate connection to the database, and `mysql_insert_id()` works uniquely within its connection, it doesn't matter how many concurrent users you have, it will maintain its uniqueness

Comment: Don't use the deprecated mysql_* interface, switch to the similar mysqli_* API.  (The answer will be the same there; this is just friendly advice about something that has security issues and is going away soon.)